# Spring Boot Microservices cannot run on Kubernetes (java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out)

Tags: kubernetes, java, minikube, spring-boot

I have a problem about running Spring Boot Microservices on Kubernetes. After I installed minikube, I started it and open its dashboard.

Here is the commands to open dashboards.

```
1 ) minikube start
2 ) minikube dashboard
```

Next, I run all services through this command.

```
kubectl apply -f k8s
```

After waiting for a certain amount of time, I got this issue shown below.

```
15:22:37.395 [main] ERROR org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigClientFailFastException: Could not locate PropertySource and the resource is not optional, failing
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.doLoad(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:197)
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.load(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:102)
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.load(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:61)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataLoaders.load(ConfigDataLoaders.java:107)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.load(ConfigDataImporter.java:128)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataImporter.resolveAndLoad(ConfigDataImporter.java:86)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.withProcessedImports(ConfigDataEnvironmentContributors.java:116)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processWithProfiles(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:311)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironment.processAndApply(ConfigDataEnvironment.java:232)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:102)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.postProcessEnvironment(ConfigDataEnvironmentPostProcessor.java:94)
 at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:102)
 at org.springframework.boot.env.EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(EnvironmentPostProcessorApplicationListener.java:87)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.doInvokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:176)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:169)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:143)
 at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:131)
 at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListener.java:85)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.lambda$environmentPrepared$2(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:66)
 at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:120)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.doWithListeners(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:114)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java:65)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:344)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
 at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
 at com.microservice.orderservice.OrderServiceApplication.main(OrderServiceApplication.java:15)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
 at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server-svc:9296/ORDER-SERVICE/default": connect timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:785)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:711)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:602)
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.getRemoteEnvironment(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:303)
 at org.springframework.cloud.config.client.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.doLoad(ConfigServerConfigDataLoader.java:118)
 ... 35 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
 at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:412)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:255)
 at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:237)
 at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609)
 at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:508)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:603)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:276)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:375)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:396)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1253)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1187)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:1081)
 at java.base/sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:1015)
 at org.springframework.http.client.SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(SimpleBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:76)
 at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
 at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:66)
 at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:776)
 ... 39 common frames omitted
```

Here is my deployment.yaml file shown below.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth-service-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth-service-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth-service-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth-service-app
          image: noyandocker/authservice
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 7777
          env:
            - name: CONFIG_SERVER_URL
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: config-cm
                  key: config_url
            - name: EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: eureka-cm
                  key: eureka_service_address
            - name: DB_HOST
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: mysql-cm
                  key: hostname

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-service-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth-service-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 7777
```

Here is the config map yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: config-cm
data:
  config_url: "config-server-svc"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: eureka-cm
data:
  eureka_service_address: "http://eureka-0.eureka:8761/eureka"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: mysql-cm
data:
  hostname: "mysql-0.mysql"
```

Here is the config-server-deployment.yaml file

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: config-server-app
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: config-server-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: config-server-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: config-server-app
          image: noyandocker/configserver
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9296
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 9296
            initialDelaySeconds: 20
            timeoutSeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 3
            failureThreshold: 2
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /actuator/health
              port: 9296
            initialDelaySeconds: 30
            timeoutSeconds: 2
            periodSeconds: 8
            failureThreshold: 1
          env:
            - name: EUREKA_SERVER_ADDRESS
              valueFrom:
                configMapKeyRef:
                  name: eureka-cm
                  key: eureka_service_address

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: config-server-svc
spec:
  selector:
    app: config-server-app
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 9296
```

I thought all the services will start simultaneously. Config Server is the Dependent Service for all other Serivces like auth service and this Auth service should not start until Config Server service is up and running.

How can I do that?

Here is my repo : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer)

Here is my docker hub : [Link](https://hub.docker.com/search?q=noyandocker)

Here is git backend system : [Link](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springappconfig)

Answer (score 1):

Reading the [config-server-deployment.yaml](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer/blob/master/k8s/config-server-deployment.yaml) you deploy a service under the name `config-server-svc`.
`config-server-svc` maps port `80` to `9296` of pods port with label `config-server-app`.
[K8s documentation for svc definition](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#defining-a-service)
Your error states:

```
GET request for "http://config-server-svc:9296/ORDER-SERVICE/default
```

Your `svc` serves to port `80` and not to port `9296` which is the pod's port.
Change the port you perform the request.
At [github spring app](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer/blob/master/apigateway/src/main/resources/application.yml#L12) you pass an environment variable called `CONFIG_SERVER_URL`.
If it's empty, you use the `localhost:9296`. It seems that you pass `CONFIG_SERVER_URL` environmental variable that spring app will read with wrong port.
When provide a value to CONFIG_SERVER_URL you have to override also the port. Try to add port 80 at [config-maps.yaml](https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer/blob/f50995902c0374751c12a904d9daf511df63158d/k8s/config-maps.yaml#L6) so the line
`config_url: "config-server-svc"` will become `config_url: "config-server-svc:80"`

Comment: Which line should I change? port : 80 targetport : 80  Is it right?

Comment: https://github.com/Rapter1990/springbootmicroservicedailybuffer/blob/master/apigateway/src/main/resources/application.yml#L12 Here you pass an environment variable called CONFIG_SERVER_URL if its empty u use the http://localhost:9296
It seems tha you pass CONFIG_SERVER_URL  with wrong port.

Comment: What should it be?

Comment: Your applications should perform GET requests at http://config-server-svc/ORDER-SERVICE/default. You should check and modify the port you provide to the application code

Comment: When provide CONFIG_SERVER_URL a value the port at ${CONFIG_SERVER_URL:http://localhost:9296} will remain the same So
provide a value for CONFIG_SERVER_URL that will contain and port

Comment: Your approach didn't help me fix the issue.

Comment: I create README.md file can you test it if you don't mind? I'vent't still solved it.

Comment: I still couldn't fix it. In Kubernetes all the services will start simultaneously. Config Server is the Dependent Service for all other Services. i.e Order, Payment, and Product.

Comment: I edited my post.

Comment: @igianmak I still couldn't fix the issue.

Comment: @qwercan you need to fix the java code to use 80 port in config-server-svc instead of 9296. The error is clear. when hitting 9296 at config-server-svc nothing listens there.
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://config-server-svc:9296/ORDER-SERVICE/default": connect timed out; nested exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out

Comment: Is it possible to write it if you don't mind? I can run config server by the port 9296 in local and docker.